# Haftarah of double parsha

Tags: minhag, haftarah

Why when we read a double parsha is the haftarah generally the haftarah of the second parsha?

Comment: The Chabad Custom is to read the Haftarah for Achrei Mot, when it is read together with Kedoshim, see http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&pgnum=1068

Answer (score 1):

According to many of the meforshim, the main reason is that we connect the haftara to the Torah portion that is read immediately before it (the maftir). Note that a days when we take out a second sefer torah for a special maftir, we read a special haftara as well.  Thus, when a double parsha is read, we would read the haftara of the second parsha. As an example, we see in [The Haftarah for a “Double Parsha”](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/sat_03_23_13/) and

[The case of the missing Haftara](https://ohr.edu/5834#_ednref3)

> An interesting halacha that concerns us is which haftara is read when
>   there is a double parsha[3]. Generally speaking, the haftara of the
>   second parsha is read, as that is the Torah reading that we just
>   concluded[4].
>
> [3]For more on the topics of double Parshiyos and which and when they
>   are combined, see recent article titled [‘Parsha Permutations’](https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5130).
>
> [4]Although the AbuDraham (Seder Parshiyos V’Haftaros) cites two
>   disparate minhagim with no actual ruling: one to read the first
>   parsha’s haftara and ‘the Rambam’s minhag’ to read the second,
>   nevertheless most other Rishonim, including the Sefer Minhagim (Minhag
>   Shel Shabbos), Mordechai (end Maseches Megilla, 831; and not like the
>   Ravyah citing the Ri HaLevi), Rambam (Seder HaTefillos Kol HaShana,
>   end par. Hamaftir B’Navi; ‘v’zu haminhag b’rov hamekomos’), Haghos
>   Maimoniyos (Hilchos Tefillah, Ch.13, 20), Shibolei HaLeket (80), and
>   Tur (O.C. 428), rule to read the second parsha’s haftara. This is also
>   codified as the proper psak by both the Shulchan Aruch (O.C. 284, 7)
>   and Rema (O.C. 428, 8) and as far as this author knows this was
>   accepted by all of Klal Yisrael [see, for example Chayei Adam (vol. 2,
>   118, 17), Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (79, 6), Aruch Hashulchan (O.C. 428,
>   7), Kaf Hachaim (ad loc. 51),and Yalkut Yosef (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch
>   O.C. 484, 6)]. **The main reason to do so is to read a haftara similar
>   to what was just read, which translates to the second parsha just
>   finished and not the first parsha.**

Comment: There are two Haftarot that are read which are completely unrelated to the Maftir preceding it.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question being asked is about a regular Shabbos, not Yom Tov. However, since Yom Tov has a special parsha, it also has a special Haftara.

Comment: @DoubleAA What he said. Special occasions like Yom Tov and Rosh Chodesh and the Arba Parshios get special Maftir's, and therefore special Haftarah's.

Comment: @DonielF But Erev Rosh Chodesh and Shabbat haGadol aren't related to anything in the Torah reading.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is a different question and could be part of the question about *Acharei Mos - Kedoshim* which also has a different haftara than this general rule. In those cases Chazal made a special rule because of the zman.

Comment: @doubleaa Along with the 11 shabbatot from 17 Tammuz until Yom Kippur

Comment: @Joel if you want sure, and those were actually never intended to match the parsha. Shabbat Hagadol was originally just for Tzav and Machar Chodesh was probably originally for 30ths of months.

Comment: A maftir with a second sefer torah is not what people usually mean by double parsha.